# Save model checkpoint only when model shows improvement in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, save

Do you know if there is a way to chose which model is saved when using Estimator wrapped in an experiment? Because every 'save_checkpoints_steps', the model is saved but this model is not necessarily the best.

```py
def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
    predict = model_predict_()
    loss = model_loss()
    train_op = model_train_op(loss, mode)       
    predictions = {"predictions": predict}
    
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode = mode,
        predictions = predictions,
        loss = loss,
        train_op = train_op,
    )

def experiment_fn(run_config, hparams):
    estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(
        model_fn = model_fn, 
        config = run_config,
        params = hparams
    )

    return learn.Experiment(
      estimator = estimator,
      train_input_fn = train_input_fn,
      eval_input_fn = eval_input_fn,
      eval_metrics = None,
      train_steps = 1000,
    )

ex = learn_runner.run(
        experiment_fn = experiment_fn,
        run_config = run_config,
        schedule = "train_and_evaluate",
        hparams =  hparams
)
```

the output is as follow:

> INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 401 into .\model.ckpt.
>
> INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0.157117 INFO:tensorflow:step = 401,
> loss = 2.95048 (636.468 sec)
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Starting evaluation at
> 2017-09-05-20:06:07 INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from
> .\model.ckpt-401
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [1/1] INFO:tensorflow:Finished evaluation
> at 2017-09-05-20:06:09
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Saving dict for global step
> 401: global_step = 401, loss = 7.20411
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Validation (step 401):
> global_step = 401, loss = 7.20411
>
> INFO:tensorflow:training loss =
> 2.95048, step = 401 (315.393 sec)
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 451 into
> .\model.ckpt.
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Starting evaluation at 2017-09-05-20:11:32
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from
> .\model.ckpt-451
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [1/1]

You see that every time it saves the last model, which is not necessarily the best.

Comment: Please, add more details. Tell us what you have done so far. What is the problem. As it is, your question is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkpoints are saved for the event that your training process is interrupted. If you don't have checkpoints you will need to restart from scratch. This is a big issue for big models that take weeks to train.

Once your training is done and you are satisfied with your model (in your words, "it is the best"), you can save it explicitly using https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#export_savedmodel. Call this method is on the `Estimator` that you used to create your `Experiemnt`. Note that this method saves "model for inference" meaning that all the gradient ops will be stripped form it and not saved.

**EDIT: In Reply to Nicolas's comment:**
You can save snapshots periodically in addition to the most recent ones using [`keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/495cc8e474e608bbd0b6c5bf91d5a22962ede7cd/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/run_config.py#L228) option to `RunConfig` that you pass when creating an estimator. If you then find that your model achieved best performance 10 hours ago, you should be able to find a snapshot from roughly that time.

Comment: What I mean is I train the model for let's say 1000 epochs, but at 500 the loss on the validation set begins the raise again while the loss on training set keeps on decreasing. And this keeps for the remaining epochs. Thus the best model occurred at 500. But the estimator saved only the last 5 models for instance. Instead of saving 500 models (if I save the models every 2 iterations), is there a better way to chose which model should be saved or not?

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: Your edit didn't really answer his question, which is also mine. Can you somehow determine a condition (like lowest validation loss) for an extra save?

Comment: I am not aware of more intelligent built-in algorithms for saving. You might want to file a feature request.